# Partial Pipeline to ask user's phone number

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

I am creating a partial pipeline to get user's phone number on signup and skip the step on subsequent logins. My partial pipeline looks like this:

```
@partial
def other_info(strategy, details, user=None, is_new=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if is_new or not details.get('email'):
        request = kwargs['request']
        return redirect('require_phone')
    else:
        return
```

On the `page-welcome.html` there is a form. Corresponding view looks like this:

```
def require_phone(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        phone = request.POST.get('phone',None)
        user = User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)
        if phone is not None:
            up = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user,   
                                                   phone = phone)
            up.save()
        backend = request.session['partial_pipeline']['backend']
        return redirect('social:complete', backend=backend)
    else:
        return render(request,'app/page-welcome.html')
```

The problem is, the request object is not passed correctly to the view and hence the user shows anonymous. I am not able to access user object and hence cannot save phone no.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get the user with

```
user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['partial_pipeline']['kwargs']['user'])
```

and then update this object, instead of trying to get it from the `request` (which will not work during the pipeline).